# How to search using app ID URI instead of app id in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to search azure AD apps under app registrations , using APP ID URI in search text box instead of the application ID?

When I am creating a web app and providing an app id URI, and I get the error that the name already exists. But I am not able to locate that App by providing the App ID URI in search text box as it expects an app id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a one-off, then you could use the [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/) and query for applications (query string is https://graph.windows.net/yourtenant/applications ).

You could of course make an application to query it also.